# Re-size image in c# with specific size and dimension

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I want to re-size an image to specifically 150*150 dimension and the image size should be less than or equal to 10kb. I already done with Bitmap, the code snippet is given below :

```
System.Drawing.Image old_Image=System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(//ImagePath);
Bitmap new_Image= new Bitmap(150, 150, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics g=new Graphics();
g= Graphics.FromImage(new_Image);
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
g.DrawImage(old_Image, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new_Image));
```

When I did like this, I got all the images with dimension 150*150 and the size is less than 10kb. But How can I ensure that the image size will be less than 10kb every time for every image of greater original size. Can I make sure it by checking it in the code side? Or is there any alternate method for this?

UPDATE:
I have compressed the image and need to do the same as long as the image size becomes less than 10kb. The loop working fine for first Iteration and for the second time, I am getting error 'Parameter not valid' when calling b.Save(ms, ici, ep). I already call dispose for Bitmap and MemoryStream after first Iteration. Then what could be the reason for this error.
The code snippet, I am using for the iteration is given below:

```
while (length > 10240)
{

  long quality = 50;

  ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
  ImageCodecInfo ici = null;

  foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
  {
      if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
      ici = codec;
  }

  EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
  ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
  ms = new MemoryStream();
  b.Save(ms, ici, ep);
  using (Bitmap bp = new Bitmap(ms))
  {
    b = bp;

  }
  length = Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length);
  ms.Dispose();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the output size of your image like this:

```
using (var testStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    b.Save(testStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    long streamSize = testStream.Length;
}
```

**b** is your image.

If you want to compress it even more to reduce the size of the image, try this:

```
//quality of the compressed image
long quality = 50;

ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); 
ImageCodecInfo ici = null; 

foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
{ 
    if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg") 
    ici = codec; 
} 

EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);

using (var testStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    b.Save(testStream, ici, ep);
    long streamSize = testStream.Length;
}
```

We're doing the same as above, but we now have the possibility to reduce the quality of the jpeg compression.

Comment: You should learn about the `using` keyword for `IDisposable` classes

Comment: @cansik. Thanks, that will work. But how can I reduce the image size further if it is greater than 10kb after checking, without any change in dimension.

Comment: @CaZbaN I've edited my answer. You can see now how to compress an image even more with jpeg compression. But I would recommend to save the image with the gif compression, because it makes the image much smaller.

Comment: @cansik That is also working. But I am trying to do the process in a loop till the size becomes less than 10kb. The loop working fine for first Iteration and for the second one, I am getting error 'Parameter not valid' when calling b.Save(testStream, ici, ep).